# ClassifierMeasurement gives reversed labels for precision and accuracy

Tags: machine-learning

According to the [standard definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) of precision and recall,

Precision = TruePositives/(TruePositives+FalsePositives)

Recall = TruePositives/(TruePositives+FalseNegatives)

In terms of confusion matrix, true positives are the elements on the diagonal, false positives are the remaining elements in the column and false negatives are the remaining elements in the row. Consider the following code:

```
In[522]:= $Version
Out[522]= "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"

SeedRandom[20];
train = Join[RandomInteger[15, {600, 10}], RandomInteger[{5, 20}, {400, 10}]] ;
labels = Join[ConstantArray[True, 600], ConstantArray[False, 400]];
classifier = Classify[Thread[train -> labels]];
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[classifier, Thread[train -> labels]];
cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
"Recall" -> cm["Recall"]
"Precision" -> cm["Precision"]
```

Its output looks like this:

[image: Confusion Matrix]

```
"Recall" -> <|False -> 0.992462, True -> 0.991694|>
"Precision" -> <|False -> 0.9875, True -> 0.995|>
```

By definition for True values,

True Positives = 597

False Positives = 5 (something that is false but classified as true)

False Negatives = 3 (something that is true but classified as false)

Hence

Precision of True values = 597/602 = 0.9916

Recall of True values = 597/600 = 0.995

As can be seen, these values do not match the values obtained using ClassifierMeasurement and are in fact opposite of whats correct. Can someone verify if its a bug? Also please correct me if my definitions are at fault.

Comment: It's a bug. Checked your code with `11.1.0` and the numbers are indeed swapped. So they fixed it in earlier version.